# SSH'ing into multiple pi's with PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssh

So I am creating a long web UI. The homepage displays the status of 5 Pi's that are being shown via Net_SSH2 library using PHP. Everything works with SSH with 1 Pi.

Here's the problem now:
 **Constant NET_SSH2_MASK_CONSTRUCTOR already defined
Constant NET_SSH2_MASK_LOGIN_REQ already defined

Constant NET_SSH2_MASK_LOGIN already defined**

And so on. Basically it's stating that I'm trying to change set constants that are set for the first Pi. I've tried trying to close the SSH when starting a new one, I've tried splitting each SSH into a separate Net_SSH2 Library, and I've tried setting timeouts and starts for each SSH, and still nothing.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on using Net_SSH2 with multiple SSH ends, or if there's another way I can SSH multiple Pi's to do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a ridiculous solution. I took the SSH2.php file in the lib, and made a variation of 5 different ones (SSH2-1.php, SSH2-2.php, ...). Changed all constant variables, and the class name to fit 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. This seemed to do the trick that allowed me to connect to my 5 Pi's.

Comment: It's not that ridiculous. It sounds like you're just working with an awfully designed library. It might be worth looking for another.